# Hibernate: Duplicate entry '173-604' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java8, Hibernate 5.2.1.Final, JPA2, Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE and MySQL.

I have a situation, where I do a `select` on a row, but get a `ConstraintViolationException`.

First of all, I have the following table. If I do a select through MySQL Workbench, it has a row of data:

```
SELECT * FROM www.person;
```

**Results**

```
 ID,              UID,                   JOINING_DATE, LASTACCESS_DATE, DISPLAY_NAME, EMAIL_ADDRESS, AVATAR, PROVIDER
'176', 'PHblCtu5odMNQEaOu9TOmGgpsJM2', '1485981515384', '1485981525475',   'One',     'one@mail.com', null,      '1'
```

Then, my code has the following:

**Java**

```
@Override
public Person findByUid(String uid, Integer provider) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" select e.* ");
    sb.append(" from ");
    sb.append("    www.person as e ");
    sb.append("  where e.uid = :uid ");
    sb.append("  and e.provider = :provider ");
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sb.toString(), Person.class);
    q.setParameter("uid", uid);
    q.setParameter("provider", provider);
    Person person = (Person) q.getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(new Person());
    return person;
}
```

where the uid (`PHblCtu5odMNQEaOu9TOmGgpsJM2`) and provider (`1`) match the row above.

But when the `q.getResultList()` above is invoked, I get:

**Error**

```
22:28:25,843 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-14) SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
22:28:25,844 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-14) Duplicate entry '173-604' for key 'PRIMARY'
22:28:25,845 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default task-14) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

**Bean**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    // private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(
    // ClassName.class.getName());

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "UID")
    private String uid;

    @Column(name = "JOINING_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Long joiningDate;

    @Column(name = "LASTACCESS_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Long lastAccessDate;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 85)
    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 55)
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_language", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_ID", referencedColumnName = "LANGUAGE_CODE", unique = true) })
    private Set<Language> languages;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_location", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<LocationPerson> locations = null;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_job_favourites", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
    private Set<Job> favouriteJobs;
```

**Question**

I didn't know you could get a `ConstraintViolationException` from executing a `select` query. If anyone can advise how I may resolve this issue, I would appreciate it.

p.s. I can do a `merge` successfully on the above Bean.

Comment: do you perform any other operations in that transaction?

Comment: Also, can add rows of table person_language, person_location, person_job_favorites which correspond to that particular person id

Comment: Yes, I do a `merge` of the same object (`person`) in the same transaction just before the `select`.  The code does not error on the `merge` but rather on the `select` though.

Comment: Ok, as the first statement in your method, put this em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT); Then merge and select. Let see

Comment: Must I add that just before I do the merge?

Comment: has to be before select but put at before merge

Comment: the flushMode didnt work?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now. Will give it a try, and let you know.

Comment: Nope, it still gets the same error. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

I needed to set each of the joined columns in the merge method:

```
            person.setLanguages(foundPerson.getLanguages());
            person.setLocations(foundPerson.getLocations());
            person.setFavoriuteJobs(foundPerson.getFavoriuteJobs());
```